# Mysql update with ' symbol in variable

Tags: mysql

i have mysql query like this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE services SET sub_service='".$subbb_service."' WHERE sub_service='".$idd."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

variable $subbb_service is with symbol '. Lets say it Hello' . So it fails query couse it looks like this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE services SET sub_service=' Hello'' WHERE sub_service='".$idd."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Now it has double '' and it dies. Maybe anyone could help me out?

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli and find out more about binding variables into query. You won't have then problems with apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

`$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));`